# Force IE9 to use Browser mode not Compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I am using  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in `head` tag. But, when I am running my application on IE9, then it is using *Browser Mode : IE9 Compat View*. 
I want my application to use only *Browser Mode : IE9*, not *Compat view.*

Answer (score 2):

I realize I'm a bit late on this but here's what I have used and it has worked for me:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Make sure this is the **FIRST** meta tag in the head of your document (I put it directly after the opening  tag).

Found this solution here: http://technicalstuffhopefullyuseful.blogspot.com/2013/09/force-internet-explorer-compatibility.html

Answer (score 1):

You also need to use HTML5 doctype declaration (`<!DOCTYPE html>`). There are also some settings in IE9. From `Tools`-menu open `Compatible settings` and uncheck all checkboxes to prevent IE to use combat view.

Comment: Yes, i already added HTML5 doctype, but nothing helpful for me.

Comment: There must not be anything before doctype, not even an empty line, a space or a tab. Also `X-UA-Compatible` must be immediately after `title` in the beginning of the `head`, especially before any `<link>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand with IE, it is extremely allergic to new things, but as long as you add a doctype declaration (doesn't really matter if it is html5) then it should behave correctly.  On the other hand, IE has never been too standards compliant.  Read [Quirksmode MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla%2527s_Quirks_Mode) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636939/fixing-the-browser-mode-in-ie-programmatically), make sure that your hosting server OS is up to date, 
For me There was many updates, suspected one is:

Update for Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility View List for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2598845)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening mostly in IE 10 browser. I tried to force the browser mode to IE 9 but according to Microsoft we cannot change browser mode and we can only change the compatibility mode. I had same problem where it work on my local machine but not working on PROD server which made to think that my local machine might got an update from Microsoft and PROD server has not been updated.The app we are testing was doing good on IE compatibility mode but was getting all kinds of weird things in IE 10.

I asked to update the prod server with the hot fix which was released by Microsoft 2 years back. But my server has 2.0 framework on it , so i asked them to move to framework 3.5 and apply this fix . Now the app does function fine and I am able to use without changing the browser mode to IE 10 compatibility mode.

Here is the link for the fix

http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2600088&kbln=en-us