# Fixing the Browser Mode in IE Programmatically

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, telerik

I have a website that **works in full compatibility on All browsers including IE 7 to 9**

I was shocked when i tried it on IE-10, Too many bugs, and because I have no time to fix this for IE-10 and i am also using third party controls "Telerik", I decided to try a simple solution by turning the Document and the browser mode back to ie9.

In Developer Tools for IE-10, If i set Manually The Document Mode to IE9 Standards and the Browser Mode to IE9, All the bugs will fly away, I have found a way that forcing the IE-10 to use the Document Mode :

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

But what about the Browser Mode? is there any way to set its value before rendering?

---

**Solution : 
The way i used in this question was correct, however the solution for me was updating the windows in the hosting server, There was many updates, suspected one is:
Update for Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility View List for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2598845)**

Comment: By the way, there are far less bugs in IE10 - if things only work in IE9 mode, you are doing something wrong. Try serving your 'normal' version (i.e. what you serve to Chrome/Firefox) to IE10 – things should work.

Comment: I suggest to try going with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100">`, which always forces the mode of the newest IE version, i.e. best support of new technologies.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach - the correct syntax for "use the best IE available" is `content="IE=edge"`

Comment: @CedricReichenbach, I don't want the newest, this website is running perfectly since one year ago, on all IE's but not the latest IE10 and IE10 for windows 8.

Comment: @RichBradshaw, It's really works like a charm on all browsers but not the IE-10 especially the Telerik controls it's totally in different style.

Comment: UA is for document mode only, In the developer tools if you changed the browser mode to IE 10 compat, OR if the website visitor used  tools > compatibility view settings> it will work because setting this will actually make the Browser Mode : IE 10 Compat, in my question i am looking for a way to set the browser by default to be IE 10 Compat, because i can't ask every visitor to add it manually to the compatibility view settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got the *document mode* sorted. Does that not solve the problem? It usually does the trick.

The *browser mode* shouldn't need to come into play, as it doesn't affect the rendering at all; it just changes the UA string, so it shouldn't have any impact on the page layout.... unless there is something in the code that tries to do a browser-specific hack by looking at the UA string.

If you have got something in your code that does that, then that's where the problem is and you should probably fix it. (using the UA string to affect page layout is generally frowned on as a bad practice anyway; there are usually better ways to do it)

If it's Telerik itself that's doing it, then I would imagine they'd have already been forced to find a fix for it (IE10 has been out for a while and they'd have had other users complaining), so you may find that updating to the latest version will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, UA is for document mode only, In the developer tools if you changed the browser mode to IE 10 compat, OR if the website visitor used  tools > compatibility view settings> it will work because setting this will actually make the Browser Mode : IE 10 Compat, in my question i am looking for a way to set the browser by default to be IE 10 Compat, because i can't ask every visitor to add it manually to the compatibility view settings.

Comment: Worked!!!, The website is hosted by a dedicated server operated by Windows Server 2008 R2, I have updated the windows using Microsoft update and the problem disappeared!,
Many Windows updates installed, suspected one is:

Update for Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility View List for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2598845)