# Website not working properly in IE 11-Otherwise works perfectly

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

With release of IE 11 my asp.net, sql server 2008 website is not working correctly. It works perfectly with Chrome and if I adjust compatibility setting in browser side it works perfectly as well, which leads me to believe that problem lies with compatibility issues.

I have added the relevant meta tag in master files of the pages as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=7"/>
<title></title>
```

When I open the page in my computer on IE 11 and look at source code it shows as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                          http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=7" /><title>

 </title><link href="../App_Themes/UserTheme/UserStyle.css" rel="stylesheet"       type="text/css" />
```

This leads me to believe that my tag is showing up correctly. However, the website still does not work properly as if the tag was not there.

I have already tired clearing Cache including by using Developer Tools.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Open the developer tools and check which document mode IE11 renders your page in.

Comment: check out my case 
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636939/fixing-the-browser-mode-in-ie-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problems with Framework 4.0 programs. It was a bug in frameworks browser detection. There is a nice blog post about the problem in ScottGus blog: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx

We solved it by installing the appropriate patch to the server.

Comment: Thanks Esa. That seems to have solved the problem somewhat as page functions well, but formatting is not great. I would try to make it compatible to even previous versions to see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new folder in your project call it App_Browsers and in the folder create a new file and call it ie.browser. In the file add this code.

```
<browsers>
  <browser id="IE11" parentID="Mozilla">
    <identification>
      <userAgent match="Trident\/7.0; rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)(?'letters'\w*))(?'extra'[^)]*)" />
      <userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
    </identification>
    <capture>
      <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+)" />
    </capture>
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="browser"              value="IE" />
      <capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
      <capability name="layoutEngineVersion"  value="${layoutVersion}" />
      <capability name="extra"                value="${extra}" />
      <capability name="isColor"              value="true" />
      <capability name="letters"              value="${letters}" />
      <capability name="majorversion"         value="${major}" />
      <capability name="minorversion"         value="${minor}" />
      <capability name="screenBitDepth"       value="8" />
      <capability name="type"                 value="IE${major}" />
      <capability name="version"              value="${version}" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>

  <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11,0) like Gecko -->
  <browser id="IE110" parentID="IE11">
    <identification>
      <capability name="majorversion" match="11" />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
      <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
      <capability name="jscriptversion"       value="5.6" />
      <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
      <capability name="javascriptversion"    value="1.5" />
      <capability name="msdomversion"         value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
      <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
      <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
      <capability name="activexcontrols"      value="true" />
      <capability name="backgroundsounds"     value="true" />
      <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
      <capability name="frames"               value="true" />
      <capability name="javaapplets"          value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsFileUpload"   value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"      value="true" />
      <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute"    value="true" />
      <capability name="tagwriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
      <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```